# Web service AJAX Post on iOS getting error 400

Tags: javascript, php, ios, ajax, html

**Background:** I wanted to create a hybrid application that can change form factor at will. This requires the app to embed a webView. This webView also should be able to talk back to the back end server. I host the back end on my Mac (localhost) with really small php code.

*API*

```
<?php
  function getStatusCodeMessage($status)
        {
            // these could be stored in a .ini file and loaded
            // via parse_ini_file()... however, this will suffice
            // for an example
            $codes = Array(
                           100 => 'Continue',
                           101 => 'Switching Protocols',
                           200 => 'OK',
                           201 => 'Created',
                           202 => 'Accepted',
                           203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',
                           204 => 'No Content',
                           205 => 'Reset Content',
                           206 => 'Partial Content',
                           300 => 'Multiple Choices',
                           301 => 'Moved Permanently',
                           302 => 'Found',
                           303 => 'See Other',
                           304 => 'Not Modified',
                           305 => 'Use Proxy',
                           306 => '(Unused)',
                           307 => 'Temporary Redirect',
                           400 => 'Bad Request',
                           401 => 'Unauthorized',
                           402 => 'Payment Required',
                           403 => 'Forbidden',
                           404 => 'Not Found',
                           405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
                           406 => 'Not Acceptable',
                           407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',
                           408 => 'Request Timeout',
                           409 => 'Conflict',
                           410 => 'Gone',
                           411 => 'Length Required',
                           412 => 'Precondition Failed',
                           413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',
                           414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',
                           415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',
                           416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
                           417 => 'Expectation Failed',
                           500 => 'Internal Server Error',
                           501 => 'Not Implemented',
                           502 => 'Bad Gateway',
                           503 => 'Service Unavailable',
                           504 => 'Gateway Timeout',
                           505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported'
                           );

            return (isset($codes[$status])) ? $codes[$status] : '';
        }

        // Helper method to send a HTTP response code/message
        // function sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '')
        function sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $content_type = 'text/html')
        {
            $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . getStatusCodeMessage($status);
            header($status_header);
            header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
            echo $body;
        }

    class testPostApi {
        function __construct() {
        }

        function __destruct() {
        }
        // Helper method to get a string description for an HTTP status code
        // From http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/



        // Main method to redeem a code
        function testPost(){
            // check for required parameters
            if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["age"])){
                $name = $_POST["name"];
                $age = $_POST["age"];

                 // Return code, encoded with JSON
                $result = array(
                                "name" => $name,
                                "age" => $age                               
                                 );
                sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
                return true;
            }
            sendResponse(400, 'Invalid request');
            return false;
        }
    }

    // This is the first thing that gets called when this page is loaded
    // Creates a new instance of the RedeemAPI class and calls the redeem method
    $api = new testPostApi;
    $api->testPost();

    ?>
```

Then a small HTML5 script running on iOS simulator

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    </head>

    <body>

        <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>

        <script>
            function submit()
            {
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    alert(xmlhttp.status);

                    /*if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {

                    }*/
                }
                var params = "name=john&age=40";

                xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost/testPost",true);

                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

                xmlhttp.send(params);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Problem:** I tested using terminal command `curl -F "name=john" -F "age=40" http://localhost/testPost/` and get back `{"name":"john","age":"40"}`. Thus proving that the back end works fine. But when I use the simulator button, the alert shows up code 400(or whatever I want when the post value is not set) bad request (3 times for status 2,3,4).

*Additional info*: Both chrome and firefox returned code 0 when using the html file. Curious enough, Safari actually provide same code as the iPhone simulator.

**Question:** What have I done wrong in the AJAX/HTML5 code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the URL. `testPost` is a folder with index.php inside. I did not know that it needed to be added into the URL. I changed:

`xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost/testPost",true);`
to
`xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost/testPost/index.php",true);`

and what do you know, it works! I tested with Safari and it works fine just like iphone safari. But for some reason Firefox and chrome still showing code 0. If anyone can comment on that, would be great! thanks!